# Yammer Login Failed With Access Denied

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, yammer

I have a web application created in Yammer, from which I got the id and secret. It is not deployed, neither locally nor globally.
The return URL is configured as a public URL.
When I try to login in an ASP.NET application, I successfully get the OAuth dialog screen, and when I select Allow, I receive an access_denied error.
What might be the cause? Does Yammer require the request URL to be precisely the one I am using? Or could it be because my application is not deployed?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm also getting the access_denied response after selecting 'Allow', works on local PC, although not on public URL, can't work it out.

Comment: To be honest, it's been a long time since I last tried... I was basically experimenting it. Please, if you happen to find a solution, do share it with the SO users!

Comment: Looks like reverse proxy is the issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864054/c-sharp-owin-login-results-in-identity-null-on-production-system

Comment: Thanks for the info!