# C# Owin login results in identity=null on production system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin, claims-based-identity

I've got an asp.net MVC 5 web project which is running fine on my development system. But for some reason, the login using Microsoft Owin with Facebook stops working as soon as I deploy the solution on my production system.

The callback always retrieves ....error=access_denied as parameter and I tracked it back to the fact that owin returns null for my identity. Any clue whats going on here?

**UPDATE**

I implemented log4net in my Owin code and was able to dive deeper:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
Stack trace:        
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationHandler<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Please not that I have already modified the facebook app to match the production urls, responses etc.

```
    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie); // Passive

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOptions.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
            AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
                        IdentityUtility.ExtendedClaimTypes.IdentityProvider,
                        "Facebook"));
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                OnReturnEndpoint = (context) =>
                {
                    if(context.Identity == null)
                        throw new Exception(context.Response.StatusCode.ToString());
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Regards,
Martin

Comment: worth checking if this is a firewall issue on the production server.

Comment: Nope... same result with deactivated firewall :-/ Any idea how I could get more information about the "access_denied" error that Owin(?) or Facebook(?) put into my callback url?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was the cause of the problem? Because I'm running into the exact same issue: Owin + MVC 5 + Facebook. Works locally but gives the exact same problem once deployed on the server (an Azure Web App in my case).

Comment: I decided to write my own login-module for oauth2 which works great for months now - and I am able to debug every little pice of code ;-) What caused the issues on my prod-environment was the reverse https proxy. I am pretty sure that facebook does NOT retrieve the expected login request OR your credentials/signature is wrong. I was missing one digit at the end for several days and owin does NOT return the facebook error response. It's really all about tracking the request that owin sends. Once you have it, debug the request in the facebook graph explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already solved it! Anyway... I'll post this answer just in case that any other lost soul (?) comes here looking for some other alternatives or workarounds.

I was fighting with a similar issue for a couple of days! In order to save time I would recommend you to try the following first:

1. Read this github thread about a workaround that OWIN needs when you are working with web cookies manager (Correlation cookie, external cookie and the SystemWebCookieManager):

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/331

2. Also... (long version) when you're working behind a load balancer or some proxy that makes a reverse with the traffic your server could be doing an overwrite over the requests schemes and finally calling facebook endpoints (/oauth) using **http** protocol (That's why it works fine on localhost or any development environment, because it runs without a LB at front). Since Facebook requires **https** in order to exchange tokens and complete the sing in process you will receive an **?error=access_denied** response (it's so frustrating +_+).

(short version):
You can assert that some request (before the reverse) was using https and overwrite the context.request attribute to restore it. And you can do it using a middleware (OWIN) to check the 'x-forwarded-proto' request header from the original request.

Just apply the OWIN middleware **before** declaring external cookies as default sign-in authentication type (SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType). The order is important here because the middleware works as a pipeline! (more info here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline)

Example code snippet:

```
// This is the middleware fixing the request scheme
app.Use((context, next) => {
  if (context.Request.Headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "https")
  {
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
  }
  return next();
});

// The following lines are related with the step 1 issue!  


app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
      AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
      CookieName = CookiePrefix + DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
      CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
    });
    
    ...
```

More info about x-forwarded-proto header here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto . The key point here is:

> The X-Forwarded-Proto (XFP) header is a de-facto standard header for
> identifying the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) that a client used to connect
> to your proxy or load balancer.

Comment: Hey... this issue was pretty old and I did a custom implementation some years ago to bypass that. Was a good learning :-) The issue was indeed the order of app.UseXXX in the startup. This is still an issue and not well documented I'd say. I mean yes, this is documented, but it's tough to understand the side effects. Thanks for you input anyhow. Hope it helps the folks out there.